# Why Sklearn LDA topic model always suggest (choose) topic model with least topics?

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.7, lda, topic-modeling, gridsearchcv

I am doing topic modeling on text data (around 4000 news articles). For that, I am using the Sklearn LDA model. While doing this, I use GridSearchCV to choose the best model. However, in almost all cases, GridSearchCV suggests the least topic as the best model.

For example 1:

```
# Define Search Param
search_params = {'n_components': [5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20], 'learning_decay': [.5, .7, .9]}

# Init the Model
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation()

# Init Grid Search Class
model = GridSearchCV(lda, param_grid=search_params)

# Do the Grid Search
model.fit(data_vectorized)
```

The best model is suggested: 5

Example 2:

```
# Define Search Param
search_params = {'n_components': [3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18], 'learning_decay': [.5, .7, .9]}

# Init the Model
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation()

# Init Grid Search Class
model = GridSearchCV(lda, param_grid=search_params)

# Do the Grid Search
model.fit(data_vectorized)
```

The best model is suggested: 3

Is this normal or it is happening only to me?

What can be the possible reason for this?

Full Code is long that is why I am not giving it here but if required I can provide it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, could you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it is simply that for your data, three topics is a better topic distribution than five topics. You didn't give the model a chance to test if three topics was any good in the first set of tests. So the answer you got was that of the choices [5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20] then 5 is best.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your dataset might be to small, so the model can't learn deep enough about its subjacent topics.